# Automate Docker Run command on Sagemaker's Notebook Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, amazon-sagemaker

I have a Docker image in AWS ECR and I open my Sagemaker Notebook instance--->go to terminal-->docker run....
This is how I start my Docker container.

Now, I want to automate this process(running my docker image on Sagemaker Notebook Instance) instead of typing the docker run commands.

Can I create a cron job on Sagemaker? or Is there any other approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can create an inline Bash shell in your SageMaker notebook as follows. This will take your Docker container, create the image, ECR repo if it does not exist and push the image.

```
%%sh

# Name of algo -> ECR
algorithm_name=your-algo-name

cd container #your directory with dockerfile and other sm components

chmod +x randomForest-Petrol/train #train file for container
chmod +x randomForest-Petrol/serve #serve file for container

account=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query Account --output text)

# Region, defaults to us-west-2
region=$(aws configure get region)
region=${region:-us-west-2}

fullname="${account}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${algorithm_name}:latest"

# If the repository doesn't exist in ECR, create it.
aws ecr describe-repositories --repository-names "${algorithm_name}" > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    aws ecr create-repository --repository-name "${algorithm_name}" > /dev/null
fi

# Get the login command from ECR and execute it directly
aws ecr get-login-password --region ${region}|docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${fullname}

# Build the docker image locally with the image name and then push it to ECR
# with the full name.

docker build  -t ${algorithm_name} .
docker tag ${algorithm_name} ${fullname}

docker push ${fullname}
```

I am contributing this on behalf of my employer, AWS. My contribution is licensed under the MIT license. See here for a more detailed explanation
https://aws-preview.aka.amazon.com/tools/stackoverflow-samples-license/

Answer (score 1):

SageMaker Notebook instance [lifecycle configuration script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebook-lifecycle-config.html) can be used to run a script when you create a notebook or at start time. In this script, you access other AWS resources from your notebook at create time or start time, say access your ECR images and automate starting docker container using a shell script. This [script](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/blob/master/scripts/auto-stop-idle/on-start.sh) show an example of how you can use cron to schedule certain actions, can be modified per your usecase

Refer more lifecycle config samples in [this](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples) github page